# IF Logic for Multiple arguments in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm hoping someone can please assist me with this problem. In the following cells, I have the following values:

```
P8 = 9 
Q8 = 7 
R8 = 5 
S8 = 4 
T8 = 2
```

Essentially, I want a formula that looks back across 4 cells and identifies if the trend has declined for 1, 2, 3 or 4 cells with an output in cell U8. U am currently trying the following formula which isn't working:

```
`=if(((T8<S8,S8<R8,R8<Q8,Q8<P8),"4"),((T8<S8,S8<R8,R8<Q8),"3"),((T8<S8,S8<R8),"2"),(T8<S8,"1"))`
```

Comment: What language are you using? Is this for an Excel spreadsheet? Please edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(AND(T8<S8;S8<R8;R8<Q8;Q8<P8);4;IF(AND(T8<S8;S8<R8;R8<Q8);3;IF(AND(T8<S8;S8<R8);2;IF(T8<S8;1;0))))`